# center fixed-width element with divs filling the extra space

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, spacing

I'm creating a webpage that has a graphical display that needs to be a fixed number of pixels wide to function properly. I would like it to be centered, and use the areas to the left and right of it to display information about it (tables).

If I COULD do this, I would have:

```
<div style="width: 50%-360px; float: left">
     <table>
         ...
     </table>
</div>
<div style="width: 50%-360px; float: right">
     <table>
         ...
     </table>
</div>
<div style="width: 720px">
```

(and whatever tweaking to force them to be on one line).

Of course that's syntactically wrong, but it should give the idea of what I want. Right now, though, shrinking the window forces the display below the tables, which is not what I want.

I tried switching to using inline-block display and just lining them up, but when the window shrinks the right table ends up on the next line.

Is there any way I can get this sort of style that will resize nicely and allow me to put scrollbars on the tables when they get too small rather than horizontally scrolling the whole page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you have some element between two `<table>`s and the whole thing has to be centered.

If that's the case, then make a `<table>` with the fixed `width` you want. Set its `margin` to be `0 auto`. This will handle the centering and avoid problems with elements vertically stacking when the window is smaller.

Make the table only have one table row (`<tr>`). That table row will have three cells (`<td>`), one for the left `<table>`, one for the element, and one for the right `<table>`. Inside of each of those cells, place your code for your `<table>`s / element.

**Edit (again)**: Updated for your last comment (Everything inside the colored `<td>`s are junk):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {border-collapse:collapse;}
        td {padding:0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="margin:0 auto; width:600px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="background:#f88;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="background:#8f8;">
                <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
            </td>
            <td style="background:#88f;">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Lorem Ipsum</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Lorem Ipsum</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Lorem Ipsum</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The above is valid HTML5. You said you were using `<table>`s so I gave an example that uses them as well

Comment: I meant I wanted to put tables in the side divs. It seems like the code I put in my post didn't show up for some reason; I fixed it. It should be a bit clearer now.

Comment: The only difference here would be that you would be putting your `<table>`s inside the `<td>`s instead of `<div>`s.

Comment: Your `<td>`s all have a fixed width, though. I tried something similar  to this by applying display:table-cell to my `<div>`s and it ended up with some weird spacing, but I think ultimately this might be the way to go.

Comment: You can remove / modify the fixed width. I specified them just to show that it can be controlled. I'm not sure why you put `display:table-cell;` on your `<div>`s, you should be able to just stick your elements in the appropriate `<td>` (it may help to give each `<td>` the width of your element going inside, also the 600 came from 150+300+150).

Comment: I'm just using display:table and display:table-cell instead of creating a meaningless table in the markup for the sake of clean code or whatever. Anyway, this works. Thank you.

Comment: This works, except that when I shrink the window the the cells refuse to get smaller than the tables inside. This means that the content extends off the left side of the screen instead of getting scrollbars (even though the cells are set to `overflow:auto`). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I added some arbitrary `<table>`s and an element. I also removed the `<td>`'s width. The resulting behavior is that the table cells of the main table are the width of their child element. If the window is made smaller than the main table then it sticks out to the right (I don't know what you'd want it to do otherwise). If you remove the fixed width (600) then it does ugly looking things when the window is made smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code given so I'm kind of guessing at what the problem might be here.
Have you tried using a media query to adjust your layout at certain window sizes?

If I'm reading the question correctly you should just be able to add a css media query at whatever size the layout breaks down.

As far as the scroll bars just add

```
overflow:scroll
```

to your css for the table.